# CA API Gateway Migration to Azure API Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ca-api-gateway

I am facing a use case of CA API Gateway migration to Azure API Gateway. I was looking some standards and experience stories, but didn't get any. Any thing similar to share here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CA API Gateway is very powerful and mature product with a lot of functionality which may not be available in Azure API management. In my experience with both products, Azure has only about 20% of functionality of CA API gateway.
The answer to your question will depend on what exactly you are trying to migrate from CA AI gateway.
If you can provide more details in what exactly you are trying to migrate, I may be able to help further.

Yuri